# How to structure files in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

For learning experience, I want to start a new rust project and work my way up. The main difficulty so far is that whenever I try to keep the files in some structure I run into some issues.

For this project the file structure is:

```
rwarden/
|- src/
|   |- main.rs
|   |- utils/
|       |- secure.rs
|- tests/
|   |- utils/
|       |- secure_test.rs
|- Cargo.toml
```

The cargo.toml content can be found bellow

```
[package]
name = "rwarden"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rust-crypto = "0.2.36"

# chatgpt suggestion, not working
#[[test]]
#name = "secure_test"
#path = "tests/utils/secure_test.rs"
```

The secure.rs file contains a function which calculates sha256 of a given string and secure_test.rs code can be found bellow

```
//secure.rs
use crypto::digest::Digest;
use crypto::sha2::Sha256;

pub fn calculate_sha256_hash(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut sha = Sha256::new();
    sha.input_str(input);

    sha.result_str()
}

//secure_test.rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use rwarden::utils::secure::calculate_sha256_hash;

    #[test]
    fn test_calculate_sha256_hash() {
        let input = "Hello, world!";
        let expected_hash = "94ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e081a6e1e7babc11c8cfae0c557a99a063ff".to_string();

        let hash = calculate_sha256_hash(input);

        assert_eq!(hash, expected_hash);
    }
}

//main.rs
mod utils {
    pub mod secure;
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Hello, world!";
    let hash = utils::secure::calculate_sha256_hash(input);

    println!("Input: {}", input);
    println!("SHA-256 hash: {}", hash);
}
```

This results in "use of undeclared crate or module `rwarden`" error while trying to run tests. The main question is how to make `calculate_sha256_hash` function visible to the test? And also it seems this way every new test must be added to cargo.toml file which also seems to be not the best option, is there an alternative way?

Comment: Normally in tests you'll see `use super::*` instead, which just imports whatever's in the "parent module", at least if you have your tests in the same source file. This can be a good thing, even if it feels strange. If you're separating, `use crate::utils::...` instead.

Comment: What is in `main.rs`? And what is in `secure.rs`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman added the `main.rs` and `secure.rs` content to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use integration tests on a binary crate. Your options are:

- Make the crate a library and use it from the binary and the test. Notice you need to make the `utils` module public as well.
- Use unit tests instead (in the same file).